# Check REQUEST_URI with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I try to limit REQUEST_URI by length with mod_rewrite and I had some problem now.
Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/?$)
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It works fine and all REQUEST_URI == lentgh(6) pointing to index.php, but I need all not matched REQUEST_URI's forbidden or redirected to error.html for ex.

Thanks in advance.
I'm using Apache > 2.4.4

**UPD**
I meant like this example:
`If REQUEST_URI == len(6)` point to index.php
`If REQUEST_URI != len(6)` redirect to another resource

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is your actual goal of this?  Do you want it to match files too?  Or all files that don't exist?

Comment: I'm asking because don't know how to split logic. If matched URI point to index.php, if **not matched** point to another resource (for ex)

Comment: "but I need all not matched REQUEST_URI's forbidden or redirected to error.html" doesn't make sense.  Could you give some examples for redirects, and your directory structure?

Comment: Why "doesn't make sense"?

Comment: Ok. I show simple ex:
`If REQUEST_URI == len(6)` point to index.php
`If REQUEST_URI != len(6)` point to google.com

Comment: okay, got it.  Please edit your question to include that, so I can remove the (-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule .*  404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create another rule which uses a negative lookahead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/?$)
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/?$)
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't know why, but first regexp not working for me. If I removed first **?** `^(!/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/?$)` then works fine.

Comment: Honestly, if @undone's answer works for you, use that. it's better than mine, and will perform better.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a more elegant (and probably faster) solution for my situation.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/.]{7}
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

If REQUEST_URI not started from /index.php or started from root '/' and length > 6 - Forbidden, else pointing to index.php